# laravel server not responding to requests unless restarting the CLI but works fine in www folder

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I'm running a Laravel app with `php artisan serve`. When I start it from the CLI, it works the first time fine. But when refreshing the URL, it stops responding and the link becomes pending in a loop in Chrome's Inspect Network tab. Then when I close the CLI and reopen it again, it works fine again the first time, but still doesn't work when restarting the server only.
But when I run the app from the `www` folder in WAMP it works fine.
So what's the problem?
Is it with the `env` file?

Comment: is there is any error message appear in your `cmd` ??

Comment: no and the /storage/log doesn't have errors even when there should be an error in the app

Comment: try to change your port like this `php artisan serve --port=9000`

Comment: still the same problem after changing the port

Comment: look there is a different solution is you use this command instead of `artisan `command `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`

Comment: yes this works but why?

Comment: really i don't know but PHP artisan always make some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version for Laravel 5.X, you will see that sometimes the `php artisan serve` command doesn’t work properly. If you face this type of problem, you can use the below command and start your server locally.

So there is a different solution: you can use your `php` cli server command instead of the `artisan` command

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

> make sure that your `PHP` is in your global variables

Comment: i'll mark this answer the best answer if there isn't a better solution

Comment: it works fine for me when i face a problem with `php artisan serve` command

Comment: but WHY does artisan have this behavior

Comment: @DanysChalifour because of `artisan` not handled like a web server it just a simple tool to simulate it in dev environoment